# Is it possible to route Slot traffic programmatically via an Az Cmdlet?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-deployment-slots

I would like to be able to route traffic from the "production" Slot to a different slot in Azure via powershell. How could I go about this that does not use RampUpRules?

We have an application in Azure currently with 3 slots (the production slot and 2 additional slots) and via a release pipeline we would like to automatically route all traffic to one of those two slots.

I have found that a "RampUpRule" can achieve this (shown in the code snippet), but it does so via the x-ms-routing-name cookie based on the given rule. I also know that the slot traffic can be done via the Deployment Slots UI on the app service but would like to automate this (if possible).

I have been unable to find a way of doing it using the existing Az cmdlets myself so far - so I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to do this.

```cs
$appName = "myapp"
$appService = Get-AzWebApp -Name $appName
$appConfig = $appService.SiteConfig

$rulesList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.RampUpRule]
$rule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.RampUpRule
$rule.Name = "LiveTraffic"
$rule.ActionHostName = "myapp-staging.azurewebsites.net"
$rule.ReroutePercentage = 100
$rulesList.Add($rule)

$appConfig.Experiments.RampUpRules = $rulesList

Set-AzWebApp -WebApp $appService
```

The RampUpRules achieve what we would like, but I am not sure if it being done via the set cookie is going to be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems works. If you set the `ReroutePercentage` of the staging slot with `100`, your users will be routed to the staging slot automatically, because the routing percentage of production is set to `0`. Unless you provide a link with `x-ms-routing-name=self` like `<a href="<webappname>.azurewebsites.net/?x-ms-routing-name=self">Go back to production app</a>`.

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#route-traffic).

Comment: Thank you, upon checking it again - it seems that's all that Azure does if the traffic is configured via the UI, it just uses the same x-ms-routing-name cookie with the slot name.